# NodeJS/MEAN.io temp files

Tags: node.js, file, filesystems, mean

I'm writing a file upload/parser using nodejs (MEAN.io to be specific). The functionality is to upload a file, parse to json, and return contents as a page. Is the upload file, via bodyParser(), automatically deleted? If so what is the timeline. If not, is there a better middleware to use that deletes the temp file, the file that is uploaded, automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bodyParser()` no longer deals with grabbing uploaded files (multipart was removed from it sometime mid-2013), so by itself there's no issue with temp files.

If you are using one of the multipart middleware packages ([busboy](https://github.com/mscdex/busboy), [formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable), et al.), you'll have to take care of temp files explicitly.  This usually isn't too hard:

```
app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    var body = "No file uploaded";

    form.on('file', function(name, file) {
        try {
            body = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(file.path));
        } catch (e) {console.log(e)}
        fs.unlink(file.path);
    });

    form.on('end', function(){
        res.json(body);
    });

    form.parse(req);
});
```

Even with this it's a good idea to have something watching for excessive temp files (like [reap](https://github.com/tj/reap) or [tmpwatch](http://linux.die.net/man/8/tmpwatch)).  Do keep in mind that most middleware puts temp files in `os.tmpdir()`, which may not be the same as `/tmp`!

Comment: Yes, I read that body parse is outdated for the file upload in the latest version of expresses. In the future I'll update to one of the multipart middelwares. Also, I've been calling fs.unlink to delete the temp file. Thanks for the answer.